# What happened to Mongoid.config.master.connection.host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am trying to get Carrierwave (0.5.1) to work with Mongoid (2.0.0.beta.20), Rails 3. I followed every step at [this guide](http://socialmemorycomplex.net/2010/06/02/gridfs-with-mongoid-and-carrierwave-on-rails-3/).

In config/initializers/carrierwave.rb, I have:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.grid_fs_database = Mongoid.database.name
  config.grid_fs_host = Mongoid.config.master.connection.host
  config.storage = :grid_fs
  config.grid_fs_access_url = "/uploads"
end
```

When I try to start my server (**rails server**). In the console, I get:

```
...config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:3:in `block in <top
(required)>': undefined method `host' for #<Mongo::Connection:
0x00000103802420> (NoMethodError)
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I've looked everywhere
and can't seem to locate why this is happening...

It seems, **Mongoid.config.master.connection.host** doesn't work anymore
in newer versions of Mongoid. Was this removed? What is the
replacement for this?

So far my workaround is the following code:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.grid_fs_database = Mongoid.database.name
  config.grid_fs_host = 'localhost'
  config.storage = :grid_fs
  config.grid_fs_access_url = "/uploads"
end
```

Line 3, should be: **config.grid_fs_host = 'localhost'**. <-- Is there a better way to dynamically indicate the host depending on environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the mongo gem has changed. So it now has to be:

```
config.grid_fs_host = Mongoid.database.connection.primary_pool.host
```